# Sqlserver - Compact And Repair Database

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

Compact and Repair Database is the way, we could make autonumber start from 1 again..

How could do Compact and Repair Database in Sqlserver 2005 using t-sql code? it is so easy to do in ms.access. But i am getting stuck with sqlserver.

How i could to write t-sql to perform this operation ?

thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset the seed value for an `IDENTITY()` column (after, for instance, having deleted all existing rows), you can use [`DBCC CHECKIDENT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx):

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ("<Table Name>", RESEED, 1);
```

This has to be done on a per-table basis.

Answer (score 0):

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (<tablename>, RESEED, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Compact and repair in MS access does not (or at least, should not) reset auto-numbers (which in SQL server are called Identity columns).

That said, I think this article will help you:
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/how-do-i-reseed-a-sql-server-identity-column/406

Comment: It does (restart numbering) if the table is empty